# merge two array's key value of same index

Tags: php, merge, associative-array

i have 2 arrays, i have to merge array within same index.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [vendor_name] => MIRAGE PET PRODUCTS
            [count_es] => 86
            [outofstalk] => 19
            [listing] => 64
            [pricing] => 2
            [discontinued] => 1
            [others] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [vendor_name] => THE HOME DEPOT
            [count_es] => 1
            [outofstalk] => 0
            [listing] => 1
            [pricing] => 0
            [discontinued] => 0
            [others] => 0
        )

)
```

this is first array and

```
Array
   (   [0] => Array
        (
            [incorrect_esc_count] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [incorrect_esc_count] => 0
        ) 

)
```

this is second array .

I want that result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [vendor_name] => MIRAGE PET PRODUCTS
            [count_es] => 86
            [outofstalk] => 19
            [listing] => 64
            [pricing] => 2
            [discontinued] => 1
            [others] => 0
            [incorrect_esc_count] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [vendor_name] => THE HOME DEPOT
            [count_es] => 1
            [outofstalk] => 0
            [listing] => 1
            [pricing] => 0
            [discontinued] => 0
            [others] => 0
            [incorrect_esc_count] => 0
        )
)
```

How can I achieve that? `The first array is getting from one variable and second array is getting from another variable. I want this sholud be in one array because for view i use angular.js and using for table

Comment: Please format your question.

Comment: Do you have any relevant code to post? Also, what language are you using? PHP? Finally, I think it should be "outofstock".

Comment: @ecg8 , i am using PHP, and 2 different  variable because its 2 query and want to show in same table

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to merge two multidimensional associative arrays into one. This code should work for you, with some comments:

```
<?php
// declare the first array, I did not add all of the key-value pairs
$marr1 = array
  (
  array("vendor_name"=>"MIRAGE PET PRODUCTS","count_es"=>86,"outofstalk"=>19),
  array("vendor_name"=>"THE HOME DEPOT","count_es"=>1,"outofstalk"=>0)
  );
// declare second array
$marr2 = array
  (
  array("incorrect_esc_count"=>1),
  array("incorrect_esc_count"=>0)
  );
// declare third empty array to hold the result
$marr3 = array();
// loop through both arrays
// this will not work if your arrays have different lengths
for ($i = 0; $i < count($marr1); $i++) {
    // merge the ith elements of both array and then push that array into the third array
    array_push($marr3, array_merge($marr1[$i],$marr2[$i]));
}
// print out result
print_r($marr3);
?>
```